# Rails paperclip change file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, file, path, paperclip

I used rmagick in Rails to convert images I upload from one file type to JPEG. I can make it call from the new image now; I did:

```
image = Magick::ImageList.new 'public/system/photos/' + @picture.id.to_s +
                              '/original/' + @picture.photo_file_name

image.write 'public/system/photos/' + @picture.id.to_s + '/original/' + 
            @picture.photo_file_name.sub(/\.\w*/, '.jpg')

@picture.photo_file_name = @picture.photo_file_name.sub /\.\w*/,'.jpg'
```

Now I have created two files, how should delete the original file, or overwrite the original file rather than create a new one like I am now?

Comment: if you're already using Paperclip why not just let Paperclip do the conversion for you.

Comment: @Jordan i kind of forgot about this problem until now, how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: the discussion in the comments, here's an example from the Paperclip docs:

> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_attached_file :photo,
>                     :styles => {
>                       :small => {
>                         :geometry => '38x38#',
>                         :quality => 40,
>                         :format => 'JPG'
>                       },
>                       :medium => {
>                         :geometry => '92x92#',
>                         :quality => 50
>                       }
> end
> ```

Note the "`:format => 'JPG'`" line. As you can see it's trivial to tell Paperclip to convert the file to JPEG while it's going about the rest of the business, so if you're using Paperclip already you don't need to do a separate conversion step with rmagick directly.